# SOIL Library Linking Errors

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, freeglut, soil

I'm trying to use the SOIL library with freeglut and glew.  I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on a Windows 8, 64bit laptop. I'm getting these errors:

```
1>libSOIL.a(stb_image_aug.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __alloca referenced in function _stbi_zlib_decode_noheader_buffer
1>libSOIL.a(image_helper.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sqrtf referenced in function _RGBE_to_RGBdivA2
1>C:\Users\UserName\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\VectorTest\Debug\testSOIL.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I found a lot of other SO questions about linking to the SOIL library, but none worked for me.
Some suggested linking in other libraries (but those seemed to be gcc specific - it was libgcc.a), others suggested building the SOIL library again.

The source code contains projects  for vc6 through vc9. I built the vc9 project and tried using it - it didn't work. When I tried to build my program, it said 'The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)'. I tried making a new static library project with the source code and building that, but I got the same 0xc000007b error.

It seems that this 0xc000007b error is characteristic of using a 32bit library on a 64bit computer or vice versa. However, the SOIL library doesn't come in a 64bit/32bit mode.
I've tried compiling for x64 instead of x86 but that didn't seem to work either.

**What do I need to do in order to get this working?**

Comment: Any help? I'd really like to fix this! :)

Comment: Compiling FreeGLUT and SOIL (statically) for X64 worked for me.  As did Win32.

Comment: Also, is it *your* program that's failing to start correctly, or the compiler?  "When I tried to **build** my program it said 'The application was unable to start correctly..." seems to imply the compiler is misbehaving.

Comment: I'm sorry for the unclear wording! The application starts up - a window is initialized.  However, within half a second of beginning, a message box pops up displaying the aforementioned message. Thanks!

Comment: That's...pretty funky.  Give [these static 32-bit libraries](http://fsrv.dyndns.org/~genpfault/so/20415381/gl-libs.7z) a try.  Make sure you set up your project to use the static runtimes (`/MTd` and `/MT`) too.

Comment: How do you want me to use those libraries? Here's my [code](http://ideone.com/c2oSc7). I added the libraries in the list of additional dependencies (and pasted them into the lib folder of visual studio's vc++).  I also used `/MT` and `/MTd` too.  Neither worked - I got the `0xc000007b` error again.

Comment: @genpfault oops, forgot to @ you!